# Build Failed Evaluating root project - Gradle

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I am building my gradle project and getting following issue.Please Help me out i am new in android programming
   No Signature found of method : org.gradle.api.internal.articraft.dsl.dependencies.defualtDependdencyHandler.compiler() is applicable for argument type :  values : com.google.android.gms:play-source:4.0.30]

```
My Gradle.build has following :
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }



dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
        compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.0.+'
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
 }
}



android {
     compileSdkVersion 19   
     buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"


sourceSets {
        main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
                manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'

              }
    }

}
```

Please let me know if i am misisngs ome thing
    Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things missed, check with [template](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.gradle/docs/android/build.gradle)

If the library was created in Android Studio, then the question should be asked for the whole project at your hand.

Comment: Thanks Paul.This template helps me alot